# How to freeze first column while horizontal scrolling in Semantic UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I have a semantic ui stackable two column grid. i want to freeze the left column when scrolling . 
I've created a [plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/1mkn80Lh) with my grid . i wanted to use sticky from Semantic but it didn't work. Do you have any idea  how to fix that?

```
<div class="ui stackable two column grid">
  <div class="column ui sticky">
    left
  </div>
  <div class=" column f-content">s
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class definitions for `column` and `sticky` are clashing. Take `.ui .sticky` out of the column and add it as a child.

```js
$('.ui.sticky').sticky();
```

```css
.f-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui two column grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui sticky">
      Sticky
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="column f-content">
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling<br />
    Scrolling
  </div>
</div>
```